# Command `builtin` used before `[` commands in all if statements

Tags: shell, built-in, shunit2

I see this throughout `shunit2`, which aims for maximum portability across old Bourne-style shell scripts (see source [here](https://github.com/kward/shunit2/blob/master/shunit2)):

```
# Determine if `builtin` command exists.
__SHUNIT_BUILTIN='builtin'
# shellcheck disable=2039
if ! ("${__SHUNIT_BUILTIN}" echo 123 >/dev/null 2>&1); then
  __SHUNIT_BUILTIN=''
fi

# Some more code ...

# ...and now a check

if ${__SHUNIT_BUILTIN} [ ... ]; then
```

Isn't `[` a special builtin in all Bourne-style shells? (i.e. `ash /bin/bash /bin/dash /bin/ksh /bin/mksh /bin/pdksh /bin/zsh /usr/xpg4/bin/sh /bin/sh /sbin/sh`)

If `builtin` exists in the shell, why would you ever need to write `if builtin [ ... ]; then`? It's literally before every single if statement in the script.

**UPDATE:**

@tripleee gave the correct answer below: `[` could be aliased. For posterity, I'm putting the POSIX shell evaluation order here:

> 1. Collect each line between pipes (called "pipelines") from standard input, which contain 1 or more commands
> 2. Break the pipeline into commands
> 3. Set up I/O for the pipeline
> 4. For each command
>
>    (a) Split the command into tokens
>
>    (b) If first token is a keyword (without quotes or backslashes) and
>    is an opening keyword (e.g. `if`, `{`, or `(`), then
>
>    i. Set up internally for a compound command
>
>    ii. Read the next command and continue until compound command closed
>
>    **(c) Check the first token of each command against the list of
>    aliases and if found, substitute the alias and go back to step (a)**
>
>    (d) Perform *tilde substitutions* (i.e. replace `~` for `$HOME`, if
>    `~` present)
>
>    (e) Perform *variable substitutions* (e.g. `$variable`)
>
>    (f) Perform *command substitutions* (i.e. `$()`'s)
>
>    (g) Perform *arithmetic substitutions* (i.e. `$(())`'s)
>
>    (h) Use `$IFS` to split the line resulting from steps `(e)` through
>    `(g)` into more tokens
>
>    (i) Perform *file wildcard expansion* (i.e. expand `*`,`?`, and
>    `[...]` pairs).
>
>    **(j) Search tokens that are commands for the path to their binary
>    using the search order `special built-ins --> functions --> regular built-ins --> $PATH`**
>
>    (k) Run command after setting up I/O redirection

I forgot that step **(c)** happens way before step **(j)**.

Comment: I don't believe `[` is a _special_ builtin -- I'm 70% sure it's just a regular built-in.

Comment: (Check the POSIX spec -- the special builtins all have a link to the "special built-in" definition in the SEE ALSO section; it's not there for `test`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy On every single one of the Bourne shells I listed (at least in their most recent versions), running `type [` and `type test` yields `[ is a shell builtin` and `test is a shell builtin` and running `command -v [` and `command -v test` each return `[` and `test`, respectively, indicating they aren't in `/usr/bin/` as a regular builtin. Thus, as far as I can tell, they are special builtins.

Comment: Presence in `/usr/bin` is really beside the point -- several operating systems have a `/usr/bin/exit`, a `/usr/bin/cd`, etc. despite such utilities being objectively useless except when implemented as special built-ins. Regular built-ins are still internal shell implementations; the built-in implementations are not executables in `/usr/bin`.

Comment: As for the demonstration of `command -v` and `type`, those demonstrate builtin-ness, but not _special_ builtin-ness. **Regular built-ins are still built into the shell itself**, though the operating system can also provide an external-to-the-shell version invoked as an executable alongside the shell-builtin one.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You're right: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.2?topic=c-command-command. So...if a particular regular built-in is not associated with a PATH environment variable search, how could it get overwritten and where does it live?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Question 2: Does POSIX shell have a way to check for special vs regular builtins?

Comment: A regular built-in can be overwritten by shadowing it with a function, as described in the specification you quote above.

Comment: I don't know that there's a formally specified way to check, though _attempting_ to shadow a builtin with a function and seeing which gets called is an easy way to distinguish.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Oh okay. So like for `echo`, I'd have to do `echo() { echo 'hi'; }` and then check if `type echo` has the word `function` in it? If it doesn't, then it's a special builtin because it wasn't overwritten.

Comment: Hmm. bash doesn't appear to implement the spec properly, if the quote above is correct -- `( cd() { :; }; type cd )` reports that `cd` is a function despite the spec you quoted indicating that special builtins take precedence over functions, and `cd` is _definitely_ specified to be a special builtin.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That is weird...using your code with `type -a` shows me it is both a function and a built-in, but it should show it only as a builtin (i.e. it should not get overwritten). If I try to use `cd`, it does nothing, certainly meaning it was overwritten. Using `unset -f cd` restores its functionality. The same happens in `zsh`.

Comment: zsh isn't _expected_ to be POSIX-flavored, so I don't expect it to try. Whereas bash has a fairly small set of high-profile deviations (`echo -e` being one of the worst), but mostly keeps its extensions in unspecified space.

Comment: ...where exactly in the POSIX spec is the quote about evaluation order edited into the question taken from? I don't find it anywhere in https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I was paraprashing the Shell Introduction (section 2.1) and "Command Search and Execution" section (Section https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01_01). It's after Section 2.9.1.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Wow, this is terrible! I can overwrite `builtin`, `unset`, and `type`. Someone could completely hose my system this way!

Comment: Eh, someone who can set up arbitrary code to run on login can already hose your system -- there's no reason someone who wants to hose your system and has that level of access would leave you with an unmodified shell binary at all.

Comment: Ahh: When `set -o posix` is active, bash doesn't allow functions to be defined with the name of a special builtin.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Good point. And I tried `set -o posix`, but it doesn't work for me. I'm on GNU bash 5.0.17 and I can still overwrite `cd` with a function.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Does it work for you?

Comment: Yes, it does work for me; when `set -o posix` is done before the attempted declaration of a function named `cd`, that function declaration fails.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Would you mind showing me an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67745982/set-o-posix-not-working-in-bash-5-0-17-on-wsl2-ubuntu-20-04. In interactive terminal, I've tried `set -o posix; cd() { :; }; cd ~`, which all "works" for me (I can overwrite `cd`). I don't get any failure messages.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67745982/set-o-posix-not-working-in-bash-5-0-17-on-wsl2-ubuntu-20-04/67747512?noredirect=1#comment119747890_67747512. I'm curious how you got yours to work.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I have good reason to suspect you weren't able to actually get unchanging `cd` to work. Please see  stackoverflow.com/questions/67745982/….

Comment: I have every intention of getting back to you on this -- please be patient. I'm doing some work for my wife's (non-software-development-related) business; the systems I use for aforementioned side job are Windows-y; I'd need to be back at one of my Linux hosts to repro.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy No problem. No need to get back. I just wanted to point you to the fact that `cd` is a _regular_ builtin, not a _special_ builtin per the POSIX standard, so setting `set -o posix` won't prevent overwritting its behavior.

Comment: I wonder if bash changed behavior on this between 4.x and 5.x -- I tested against the former.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy And as always, THANK YOU SO MUCH for all your help! I greatly appreciate how quick your responses have been and how much you have helped me understand things!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Oh that would be frustrating! I asked the person who posted the answer in the question to check against 5.x for myself. In fact, I wonder if it had to do with the updated POSIX standard since the standard lists each builtin it considers special. Who knows!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the user could have shadowed it with an alias or function, and using `builtin` bypasses those, but isn't completely portable to old shells.

Comment: Aaaaah! I forgot about aliases! I'm going to update my question with the POSIX shell evaluation order. Thanks!