# `set -o posix` Not Working in Bash 5.0.17 on WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: bash, set, posix

As mentioned in the title, the `set -o posix` option does not appear to be working in GNU/Linux bash 5.0.17 (I'm not sure it's specifically related to WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04 or anything, but noted it in case it is working for others on their machines).

I can turn it on and off:

```sh
$ set -o |grep posix
posix        off
$ set -o posix
$ set -o |grep posix
posix        on
$ set -o posix
$ set -o |grep posix
posix        off
$ set -o posix
$ set -o |grep posix
posix        on
```

but, for example, when on I am able to do the following

```sh
$ set -o posix
$ set -o |grep posix
posix        on
$ type cd
cd is a shell builtin
$ cd /
$ ls
bin   dev  home  lib    lib64   lost+found  mnt  proc  run   snap  sys  usr
boot  etc  init  lib32  libx32  media       opt  root  sbin  srv   tmp  var
$ cd() { :; }
$ type cd
cd is a function
cd ()
{
    :
}
$ cd ~
$ ls
bin   dev  home  lib    lib64   lost+found  mnt  proc  run   snap  sys  usr
boot  etc  init  lib32  libx32  media       opt  root  sbin  srv   tmp  var
$ unset -f cd
$ cd ~
$ ls
Desktop  Documents  Downloads  Music  Pictures  Public  Templates  Videos
```

I am able to override all special builtins (including `builtin` and `type`!). Also, I am not root, but just in my user account. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

@Shawn, @oguzismail, and @Dan all give the correct answer below: `cd` is a *regular* builtin. I wanted to add some clarification as I think it will be important for learners like me:

@oguzismail correctly points to the section of [Classic Shell Scripting](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596005954) that explains that `cd` is a regular built-in:

> For this reason, you can write a function named cd, and the shell will
> find your function first, since cd is a regular built-in

- Section 7.9 (pg. 261 in Kindle Edition)

My confusion came from the statement in the summary:

> Built-in commands exist either because they change the shell’s
> internal state and must be built-in (such as cd), or for efficiency
> (such as test).

- (Section 7 Summary, pg. 264 in Kindle Edition)

Here, `cd` is a builtin, but as the author states previously, it is a *regular* builtin. It has to be a command built into the shell because the command changes the internal state of the shell (i.e. it changes the current/present working directory of the shell), but it can be either a *regular* or *special* builtin. As @Dan mentions, the [POSIX IEEE Std 1003.1-2017 standard, Section 2.14](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_14) defines it as a *regular* builtin. (For at least one reason why, Section 7.9 of [Classic Shell Scripting](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596005954) shows that doing so permits the programmer to customize its behavior.)

Be Warned Though! (NB = Nota Bene): If you do choose to overwrite `cd` with a user-defined function, use `command cd` within the function definition where you want to actually change directories. The function `command` skips looking for functions in the POSIX-defined search order of `special built-ins --> functions --> regular built-ins --> external commands on $PATH`. Otherwise, if you use `cd` within your user-defined function `cd`, you will most likely end up with an infinite recursion loop. ([Classic Shell Scripting](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596005954) also covers this point.)

Comment: Which part of the behaviour is unexpected?

Comment: @choroba According to the Bash docs, you should not be able to create functions of the same name as special builtins in POSIX mode (see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-POSIX-Mode.html, Number 15 and 16).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set -o posix` works fine:

```
  $ set -o posix
  $ set () { :; }
bash: `set': is a special builtin
```

`cd` is not a *special* built in, nor is `builtin` or `type`.

The list of "special builtins" is [clearly defined](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_14) in the posix specification.

A "special built-in" is distinct from any other command which a shell may or may not implement as a built-in.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I made a dumb mistake regarding `cd`. It is a regular built-in, not a special one. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 3):

The key here is what `bash` considers a *special builtin* to be. I had to dig into [the source](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/builtins/mkbuiltins.c) to find a list:

```c
/* The Posix.2 so-called `special' builtins. */
char *special_builtins[] =
{
  ":", ".", "source", "break", "continue", "eval", "exec", "exit",
  "export", "readonly", "return", "set", "shift", "times", "trap", "unset",
  (char *)NULL
};
```

They're also [described in the POSIX documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_14) as being distinct from [regular built-ins](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap01.html#tagtcjh_18).

And indeed...

```sh
$ bash --posix
bash-4.4$ break() { :; }
bash: `break': is a special builtin
bash-4.4$ type break
break is a special shell builtin
bash-4.4$ type cd
cd is a shell builtin
```

Note the different output from `type` for `break` and `cd`, because the latter isn't in that list.

Comment: That is SO WEIRD because every book on the subject of shell scripting states that `cd` has to be a special builtin because you can't change directories using a library from an external location. Namely, Classic Shell Scripting by O'Reilly and Shell Programming in Unix, Linux, and OS X by Addison-Wesley, not to mention numerous online resources.

Comment: @A.Hendry I finally found where POSIX defines the special ones: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_14 (As opposed to *regular built-in utilities* https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap01.html#tagtcjh_18)

Comment: is this a WSL2 thing, or does it apply to Bash in general? Another colleague of mine said they weren't able to redefine `cd` in a user function after using `set -o posix`. I also noticed you used versio. 4.4 in your example, but I'm on version 5.0.17. Can you confirm it works in version 5 and whether or not the issue is related to WSL?

Comment: @A.Hendry It's a bash thing.

Comment: I can confirm that bash 5.1.4 has the same behavior in posix mode - `cd` can be overridden as a function, the special ones like `break` can't.

Comment: @oguzismail Oh my gosh *face palm*, you're absolutely right. How embarrasing. I even referenced that in another post!